# Checking Linux kernel interrupt that resumes the system after suspend

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt

Does anyone know how to check which interrupt wakes up the system from suspend?

Answer (score 1):

This question is very arch specific but most platforms have a interrupt controller which tells you the active interrupt number when interrupt happens. If the question is related to Linux,
for example of ARM architecture, you can retrieve the interrupt number at arch_irq_handler_default. You can just keep tracking of latest irq number when process preemption (both kernel preemption and user preemption are both possible)happens. 
You can refer the codes in arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S for arm platform to understand the interrupt handling flow.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Linux, the mechanism used to alert the operating system to suspend the machine (e.g. when closing the lid) and to wake up again is defined by the platform. In Linux' case, the process is ultimately controlled by userland, as you can suspend "by hand" and configure to not suspend on lid close, etc.